# Iteration Through N Number Of Children of a Model Instance - Entity Framework/LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Hope I spoke correctly in the title. Basically, I have a MVC/Entity Framework application (Code First) and I can clearly see that there's already iteration happening (provided from the scaffolding) to write whatever labels, editor-for, etc. foreach object dynamically created from the user of the application (Create.cshtml), etc.

What I need now is to not have to specify each property name for all the labels, editorfor, etc. I need to have the code just look for each property of the object and display everything but the ID..

I figured this would have been pretty straight forward. But, in addition to the neglecting of such use from the amazing architects of the scaffolding option, I haven't figured it out either. I'm desiring, if possible, to use Entity Framework (or I guess the querying would be LINQ, right?), lambda expressions, in fashion of the rest of the beautiful code.

p.s. I see that there're a few questions out there that are related to this question in some way. But not close enough to what I am asking to solve this problem..

Based on the number of views and no answers, perhaps an example is needed. Below is a class called Item that has a number of properties. Each time the administrator adds another Item, a new instance is created and these properties are set. Well that's fine and dandy, I just don't want to have to specify what all the properties are.. I want to say something like, foreach(property in Item){Html.DisplayNameFor(Item.PropertyName)} and then again, where appropriate, foreach(property in Item){Html.EditorFor(Item.PropertyName)} That way a label and an input box will be created without me having to specify: "Item.Name, Item.Category, Item.Price, Item.Blah" and then if I add more properties I have to go back to my code again and add more stuff...

So, that being said, here's my class:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 10000000)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

and now here's where I need the dynamic stuff:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(foreach(modelProperty in model.Properties)
        {modelProperty.PropertyName}
        </th>
    <tr>
</table>
```

and

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(foreach(modelProperty in model.Properties)
        {modelProperty.PropertyName}
        </th>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your item class, you can hide specific columns by turning off scaffolding:

```
public class Item
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view, you can do this:

```
@model Item

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

This will automatically search for these views:

- ~/Views/{CONTROLLER}/EditorTemplates/Item.cshtml
- ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Item.cshtml
- (a few others for .vbhtml too)
- ~/Views/Shared/Object.cshtml

If it none of those exist, it will go to the default object editor. It examines the model metadata to build up the form. The model metadata is built automatically via reflection of the properties.

What you're looking for, doing a loop over an object properties, takes a bit more and will require reflection. In your view, I would strongly recommend against that - too much logic and views should be just simple templates.

As an example, I wrote up a custom Object.cshtml template to match how I lay out forms. This goes in ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml. It will automatically loop over all the properties (I omitted a couple customized extensions)

```
<dl>
    @foreach (var prop in
        ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
            .Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
    {
        <dt>@Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)</dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName)
        </dd>
    }
</dl>
```

You'll find very quickly that the basic editor templates won't cover everything you need. For very basic forms, yes. Complex objects, not so much.

For reference, here's how you'd loop all properties with reflection, but again, bad and redundant idea to actually do this:

```
@{

    // Not good way, with reflection. Have to check for all the various dataannotations
    // yourself for each property.
    var properties = Model.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        @property.Name
    }


    // Better way (sort of), loop the data which is already built
    // in the view with metadata properties.
    foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {
        @property.DisplayName
    }
}
```

You can [check here for more documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.modelmetadata.aspx) on what ViewData.ModelMetadata contains.

Comment: Can't use 'var'? Does it give you an error? It would be better if you posted more code that you tried. Or toss it up on something like pastebin.com for further review.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what [DisplayForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) is used for?